# Is there any alternative to JSON_TABLE?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a table in MySQL with a column with json like this

```
id col
1  [{"key": 1, "value": 9}, {"key": 2, "value": 8}, {"key": 3, "value": 7}, ...]
2  [{"key": 1, "value": 6}, {"key": 2, "value": 5}, {"key": 3, "value": 4}, ...]
...
```

I need to transform it in

```
id key value
1   1    9
1   2    8
1   3    7
2   1    6
2   2    5
2   3    4
```

Because of company and server, I cannot create temporary table. Also I cannot use `JSON_TABLE`. It should be in one query. Is there any solution? OR I should update mysql to version 8?

Comment: Can you use a recursive CTE?

Comment: You'll need to upgrade to MySQL 8 for that.

Comment: How can you not be able to create a temporary table whilst still being able to update to MySQL8? Are you sure you have this right?

Comment: mysql v5.7 supports json_keys and json_extract functions, which can return keys and values from a json document, but you would still need to convert the results into multiple  rows as opposed to a list of values in a single field value.

Comment: Can You Please Tell me The Datatype Of  `col` column

Comment: Seems the data should have been stored in a child table. JSON in a column may sound great but in reality just makes life difficult in 90% of actual implementations

Comment: *Is there any solution?* Not a problem. What is maximal key:value objects per one row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution I tested on MySQL 5.7:

```
select * from (
  select id,
   json_unquote(json_extract(col, concat('$[',n.i,'].key'))) as `key`,
   json_unquote(json_extract(col, concat('$[',n.i,'].value'))) as `value`
  from mytable
  cross join (select 0 as i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5) as n
) as t
where t.`key` is not null
order by id, `key`;
```

Output given your test data:

```
+------+------+-------+
| id   | key  | value |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 | 1    | 9     |
|    1 | 2    | 8     |
|    1 | 3    | 7     |
|    2 | 1    | 6     |
|    2 | 2    | 5     |
|    2 | 3    | 4     |
+------+------+-------+
```

It's up to you to make the subquery with the `union`'s have enough terms to account for the longest JSON array you might encounter.

If that seems too difficult, then maybe JSON is not the right way to store your data. You should store them on one individual row per object, with normal columns `key` and `value`.

Comment: Wow that's great example with expected result for key and value pair to extract data in a table format if your mysql version is with 5.7 ....

Thanks @Bill Karwin