# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; when using JSON_TABLE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I created a custom repository query on symfony in order to calculate prices. Here is the query:

```php
       $sql = " SELECT
                   SUM(sub.totalPriceWT) AS totalPrice,
                   c.label
               FROM (
                   SELECT
                       v.id,
                       (
                           SELECT SUM(priceWT)
                           FROM JSON_TABLE(
                               JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.bdc.service.operator.entries[*].priceWT')),
                               '$[*]' COLUMNS(priceWT DECIMAL(10, 2) PATH '$')
                           ) der
                       ) AS totalPriceWT
                   FROM valid v
                   JOIN sheet s ON v.sheet_id = s.id
                   JOIN step st ON s.step_id  = st.id
                   WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.type')) = 'bdc'
                       AND (
                           (YEAR(s.sent_date) = :currentYear AND CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.anticipated') AS SIGNED) = :anticipated2)
                           OR
                           (YEAR(s.sent_date) = :previousYear AND CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.anticipated') AS SIGNED) = :anticipated1)
                       )
                       AND s.perimeter_id = :perimeter
                       AND JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.bdc.service.operator.entries')) IS NOT NULL
                       AND st.slug != 'rejetee'
               ) AS sub
               JOIN valid v2 ON sub.id = v2.id
               JOIN sheet s2 ON v2.sheet_id = s2.id
               JOIN cost_center c ON s2.cost_center_id = c.id
               GROUP BY c.id
               ";
      
       $conn = $this->manager->getConnection();
       $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindValue('perimeter', $perimeter->getId());
       $stmt->bindValue('currentYear', $year);
       $stmt->bindValue('previousYear', $year - 1);
       $stmt->bindValue('anticipated1', 1);
       $stmt->bindValue('anticipated2', 0);
       $resultSet = $stmt->executeQuery();
       $resultBDC = $resultSet->fetchAllAssociative();
```

The issue is that I get this kind of error :

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
> error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
> the right syntax to use near '( JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac,
> '$.bdc.serv...' at line 9

I can't seem to find any problem with my syntaxing. I thought maybe it was a server problème because what's weird is that the error says **"check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server"** but I thought I'm on MySQL.

edit: I'm on MariaDB.

I type the following commands:

```
php bin/console debug:container --env-vars
php bin/console debug:config doctrine dbal
```

and the output showed that I was indeed on mySQL /pdo_mySQL.

I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: The error tells that you have some problems with JSON_TABLE() function call. Does your MariaDB version is recent enough? 10.6.0 or newer needed..

Comment: `"check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server" but I'm on mySQL.`...I think if it says MariaDB, you're definitely on MariaDB. Demo (mysql): https://dbfiddle.uk/1vZUU-wJ (mariaDB): https://dbfiddle.uk/3xFxPnBn

Comment: *but I'm on mySQL* See the output for `SELECT VERSION()'`.. maybe you connect to wrong server?

Comment: Ok you are right I'm on mariaDB server and I'm on version 10.3.38. However I can't upgrade the server (server managed by the company admins). Is there a substitute to JSON_TABLE ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69181190/is-there-any-alternative-to-json-table maybe? More possibilities [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mariadb+json_table+alternative). It's not a topic I'm famliar with specifically, but there seem to be a few suggestions around.

Comment: In the future, please understand that MariaDB and MySQL are different products, and they are not compatible. I've edited your text and tags to make it more clear you are using MariaDB.

Comment: The best workaround if you are using a version of MariaDB that does not support full JSON functions and you can't upgrade to MariaDB 10.6 is to refrain from storing data in JSON when you need to access individual fields within the JSON document. Store data in normal rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

From https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/

> JSON_TABLE was added in MariaDB 10.6.0.

Not all JSON functions are implanted in MariaDB, and some were only belatedly implemented.